# Discord.net bot Embed Message

Tags: c#, discord.net

I am trying to implement embedded messages for my bot.  I know that I need to fill an `Embed` Object with the specific informations.  But how can I send it to the Channel?  When I use `e.Channel.SendMessage(string);` it can't send an `Embed` object, it will just send strings.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
var eb = new EmbedBuilder();
eb.WithDescription("some text");
await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("", false, eb.Build());
```

In Discord.NET 1.0.

0.9.6 doesn't support embeds.

Answer (score 5):

With Discord.Net 2.0.1 syntax will look a little different.

```
EmbedBuilder builder = new EmbedBuilder();

builder.WithTitle("Ice Wizard Stats");
builder.AddField("Cost", "3", true);    // true - for inline
builder.AddField("HP", "665", true);
builder.AddField("DPS", "42", true);
builder.AddField("Hit Speed", "1.5sec", true);
builder.AddField("SlowDown", "35%", true);
builder.AddField("AOE", "63", true);
builder.WithThumbnailUrl("http://...");

builder.WithColor(Color.Red);
await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("", false, builder.Build());
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use Discord.net 1.0
Here is an example showing `EmbedBuilder()`

```
var builder = new EmbedBuilder();

builder.WithTitle("Ice Wizard Stats");
builder.AddInlineField("Cost", "3");
builder.AddInlineField("HP", "665");
builder.AddInlineField("DPS", "42");
builder.AddInlineField("Hit Speed", "1.5sec");
builder.AddInlineField("SlowDown", "35%");
builder.AddInlineField("AOE", "63");
builder.WithThumbnailUrl("url");

builder.WithColor(Color.Red);
await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("", false, builder);
```

Sorry I am a Clash fanatic. The `await Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync("", false, builder);` sends the Embed to the channel :).