# How to send file attachment with embed discord.net webhook c#

Tags: c#, .net, embed, webhooks, discord.net

I've tried every solution on adding an embed on a web hook but none work on my case or am I missing something?

I'm using Discord.Net v2.2.0

here's part of my code

```cs
var DCW = new DiscordWebhookClient(DCWebhook)

using (var client = DCW)
{
    var eb = new EmbedBuilder();
        eb.WithDescription("some text")
      .Build();

    await client.SendFileAsync(filePath: "file.txt", text: null, embeds: eb);
}
```

this code shows an error

> cannot convert from 'Discord.Embed' to
> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<Discord.Embed>

I tried this code and had the error fixed

```cs
await client.SendFileAsync(filePath: "file.txt", text: null, embeds: (IEnumerable<Embed>)eb);
```

I built and ran the .exe file and an error occured on console

> Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast
> object of type 'Discord.EmbedBuilder' to type
> System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable 1[Discord.Embed].

references:
[Send a Discord Embed via Webhook C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59398782/send-a-discord-embed-via-webhook-c-sharp)

[Discord.net bot Embed Message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44300770/discord-net-bot-embed-message)

[ModifyAsync Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47672300/modifyasync-not-working)

https://discord.foxbot.me/docs/api/Discord.EmbedBuilder.html

I know most solutions above work but not in my case.
I would really appreciate examples on how to solve this. thanks!

Comment: Can you please have your codes copy pasted here, instead of the image of the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So from what I can see is, that you are trying to pass `IEnumerable<Embed>` to `SendFileAsync`. The thing is, that you can not cast `EmbedBuilder` to `IEnumerable<Embed>`. You need to pass it an `IEnumerable<Embed>` which you can get with something like an array (`Embed[]`).

```cs
// This creates the Embed builder
var eb = new EmbedBuilder();
    eb.AddField("RandomField", "Hello, my name is random Field"); 

// Here you make an array with 1 entry, which is the embed ( from EmbedBuilder.Build() )
Embed[] embedArray = new Embed[] { eb.Build() };

// Now you pass it into the method like this: 'embeds: embedArray'
await DCW.SendFileAsync(filePath: "C:\RandomFile.txt", text: "Embed", embeds: embedArray);
```